# Spring Boot + Unit testing a function using UUID in local scope

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following function that I want to write unit test for:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyMessageServiceTests {    

    @Autowired
    MyMessageService  myMessageService;


    @MockBean
    MyMessageRepository myMessageRepository;    

    public List<MyMessage> updateAndSelect() {
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String identifier = uuid.toString();
                myMessageRepository.updateForSelect(identifier);
                //a private method of the service that returns records based on identifier            
                return findAllByIdentifier(identifier);
            }
}
```

The function first updates records and puts a `UUID` against them and then reads the records based on that `UUID` identifier, Now I cant Mock `UUID` obviously but when I run the following unit test the verify fails because the method `findAllByIdentifier` is actually called with a different `UUID` then I am passing in, because `updateAndSelect` creates a new `UUID` within itself

```
        @Test
        public void testUpdateAndSelect(){
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            String identifier = uuid.toString();
            when(myMessageRespository.findAllByIdentifier(identifier)).thenReturn(myMessages);
            when(serviceUUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);
            myMessageService.updateAndSelect();
            verify(myMessageRespository).findAllByIdentifier(identifier);

        }
```

Comment: You can use any(String.class) instand of passing uuid.toString();

Comment: Thanks @RaviSapariya just thinking how would that work because the verify will complain if the value in the side function is not identical in the service function and the unit test

Comment: As this is a Spring Boot test you have other options than pure mocking, i.e. SpringFramework provides an `IdGeneartor` that you can implement to provide a known UUID each time plus impls for generating UUIDs as standard e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/IdGenerator.html

Comment: @DarrenForsythe thats the answer...works like a charm! please put that in answer and I will mark it.